# How to make a Form load before opening another?

Tags: c#

I am creating a C# application that opens multiple forms at once. This one currently works by opening the forms all first, THEN loading their content. How do I force the form to open, load its content, then open the next?

The repeat action is what triggers multiple forms opening at once.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    ShowForms();
    Application.Run();
}
static void ShowForms()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int formCount = 0;

    RepeatAction(5, () =>
    {
        formCount++;

        int x = random.Next(0, 1000);
        int y = random.Next(0, 1000);

        Form1 form = new Form1
        {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
            ShowInTaskbar = false,
            Location = new Point(x, y)
        };

        form.FormClosed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (--formCount > 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            Application.ExitThread();
        };

        form.Show();
    });
}
```

Comment: There is no separate "load their content" action in Winforms.  It is done when you construct the form object, its InitializeComponent() method is called by the constructor.  Most programmers confuse it with "completely painted", which can take a while on a form that's crammed full of controls and bitmaps.  The Shown event is available for that, call Update() to ensure the controls are painted as well.

Answer (score 0):

`form.Show();` causes to show the form. So either make `RepeatAction` to a sequential loop or keep an array of forms and then iterate through the array and call the `form.show()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a simple loop, try creating a callback method that you give to each form when it's instantiated, that calls back to your main logic from the end of its Load event (or whatever handles form population). The callback will then keep track of how many forms have been created and terminate the "loop".

It might look something like:

```
static volatile int formCount = 0;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        ShowForms(5);

        Application.Run();


}

static void ShowForms(int formsLeft)
{
    if(formsLeft == 0) return;

    Random random = new Random();                    

    int x = random.Next(0, 1000);
    int y = random.Next(0, 1000);

    Form1 form = new Form1
    {
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
        ShowInTaskbar = false,
        Location = new Point(x, y),
        LoadCallback = ()=>ShowForms(formsLeft - 1);
    };

    form.FormClosed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (--formCount > 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        Application.ExitThread();
    };

    formCount++;
    form.Show();        
}
```

You would then need to add a LoadCallback property to Form1, of type Action, or a custom named delegate that takes no parameters and returns void. You then simply call `LoadCallback()` at the end of whatever method populates your form, and it comes back to this code with one fewer form to create, until there are none.